# Hosting a laravel project on openshift

Tags: ssh, laravel-5, openshift

I am pretty new to hosting on Openshift and also pretty new to Laravel.

I have a laravel project on my local system. What are the steps to successfully host the project on Openshift.

I tried the Quickstart guide, to load from a github repo. So i uploaded my project onto [github](https://github.com/Dsupreme/MaqAssignments)

I had the env files kept secret by adding them in gitignore ( Should this be done ?)

I have the ssh key set up with rhv setup. Made a private key with Puttygen and can connect via Putty.

I checked if all the code has been uploaded to the openshift server with Putty

But my [website](http://grammyawards-scriptkiddies.rhcloud.com/) gives a 500 Internal Server error.

What am i doing wrong ?

Edit: I connected to the server via ssh and found this error

PHP Parse error:  syntax                               error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable                               (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/lib/openshift/558bfb764382ec89c3000084/app-r                              oot/runtime/repo/public/index.php on line 50

Edit 2: On exploring the code on line 50 This is supported only on PHP5.5 or above. So i guess this is the problem ?

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

Is there any fix ?
How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try checking out the laravel 5 quickstart on the OpenShift Hub (https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/115-laravel-5-0), check out the source code and see what modifications were made to make it run correctly on OpenShift and then incorporate those changes into your application.

Comment: Finding modifications is pretty cumbersome. I would recommend to setup the basic code from the repo itself. Then create a local repo by cloning with git via ssh. From here adding your code will work fine.